# Divisibility of $\binom{n}{p}$ by $p$, with $p$ prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A theorem of E. Lucas asserts that, if $p$ is a prime and $n,k$ are natural numbers, then :

> $$\binom{n}{k}\equiv\binom{\lfloor n/p\rfloor}{\lfloor k/p\rfloor}\binom{n\text{ mod }p}{k\text{ mod }p}\pmod{p}$$

As a special case (replacing $k$ with $p$), we can see that :

$$\binom{n}{p}\equiv\lfloor\frac np\rfloor\pmod{p}$$

And, in particular :

$$p\mid\binom np\Leftrightarrow p\mid\lfloor\frac np\rfloor$$

**First question** : is there a way to prove that last property in some direct manner (ie : without having to know the general case) ?

**Second question** : I've found a numerical evidence that de $p$-adic valuation of $\binom np$ and $\lfloor\frac np\rfloor$ are equal (for $p$ prime). Is it true and how to prove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I answer to myself ...

We know that :
$$p!\binom np=n(n-1)\ldots(n-p+1)$$

Let $i$ be the sole integer in $\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$ such that $p\mid n-i$. We can see that :

$$\frac{n-i}p\in\mathbb{N}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{n-i}p\leqslant\frac np<\frac{n-i+p}p$$

so that :

$$\frac{n-i}p=\lfloor\frac np\rfloor$$

Let :
$$A=\prod_{0\leqslant j<p,\,j\neq i}(n-j)$$

The first equality can now be rewritten as :

> $$(p-1)!\binom np=A\lfloor\frac np\rfloor$$

and since neither $(p-1)!$ nor $A$ is divisible by $p$, we conclude that $\binom np$ and $\lfloor\frac np\rfloor$ share the same $p-$adic valuation. In particular :

$$p\mid\binom np\Leftrightarrow p\mid\lfloor\frac np\rfloor$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach your problem is the following:

Recall $\cfrac{\binom{n}{p}}{\binom{n-1}{p}} = \cfrac{n}{n-p}$.

Let $\nu_p(n)$ denote the exponent of the highest power of $p$ dividing $n$.

Note that $n \equiv n-p$ mod $p$.

You can now easily prove your result:

$\nu_p\left(\binom{n}{p}\right) = \nu_p\left(\lfloor \cfrac{n}{p}\rfloor\right)$ for all prime $p$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by induction on $n$ using the following.
Take the base case $n=p$, the result is clearly true.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about your argument ? The relation you give can be rewritten $(n-p)\binom np=n\binom{n-1}p$. If $p\nmid n$, this leads to $\binom np\equiv\binom{n-1}p\pmod p$, and I don't see how to go further.

Comment: There are several cases for you induction. If $p \nmid n$, the induction is immediate. Then you need to consider when $p \nmid$ but not $p^2$, etc